# Is there any way that I can read the setting values in the Settings.app?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to know the system configuration for "Auto-Capptalization", "Auto-Correction", “Check Spelling”, etc, whether they are turned on or off from the Settings.app (Settings/General/Keyboard/).

I do not know whether I have the right to access these information?  If yes, which API can I use?

Comment: What could you possibly do with this information?  UIText... Elements automatically take these settings into account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just need that information, so I can do something in my app:)

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for this and find that you does **not** have the right to access these information and you also can't override the system's setting:[Why doesn't UITextSpellCheckingTypeYes override Settings/General/Keyboard/Check Spelling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272646/why-doesnt-uitextspellcheckingtypeyes-override-settings-general-keyboard-check)