# Check user settings for Check Spelling and Autocorrect

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, autocorrect, uitextinputtraits

I would like to make switch for turning on/off `AutoCorrect` and `CheckSpelling` function in `UITextView`.

As far as I know when user disabled `CheckSpelling` in iOS (Settings > General > Keyboard > Check Spelling) there is no way to turn it on programatically. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624461-spellcheckingtype) that `spellCheckingType` do override iPhone settings. But [as it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272646/why-doesnt-uitextspellcheckingtypeyes-override-settings-general-keyboard-check) it doesn't.

It works only when user have `Autocorrect` and `CheckSpelling` turned on, they can be turned off programatically, sadly the other way around it's not working.

So is there a way to check if the user has turned off these properties in iOS Settings? Then I could provide some kind of feedback to user how can he 
turn them back on.